# Return the regex match if any, else ''

Tags: python, regex

Is there something more pythonic than doing this:

```
re.search(regex, s).group(1) if re.search(regex, s) is not None else ''
```

or

```
def getmatch(regex, s):
    m = re.search(regex, s)
    return m.group(1) if m is not None else ''
```

to get the first match group of a regex if any and `''` else?

Would there be a one-line solution for this? (I know they can be bad sometimes, but here I'm curious about if there would be a nice one-liner)

To be more precise, is there a solution that is both 1) one-line and 2) without repetition of `s` and `regex`? (my first proposal has such a repetition).

Comment: Sure, just use `m = re.search(....)` and then check `if m:`...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I forgot to mention the one-line thing, see update.

Comment: That sounds like an "opnion-based" question. What makes a "one-liner" better than 2-line solution? Are you running out of disk space?

Comment: Readability counts. I would prefer 3 lines over 80 chars one-liner which isn't clear.

Comment: If you're aiming for concision, your line probably is best. If you're aiming for efficiency, the 2-line solution proposed by Wiktor is best (you avoid computing `re.search` twice when it's not `None`). It's also best if you're aiming for readability/maintainability. You should probably reflect on what concision will help with.

Comment: You can remove the `not None` part as it returns False, and save the space of two words :) `return m.group(1) if m else ''`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's not opinion-based. If there is a solution that is both 1) one-line and 2) without repetition of `s` and `regex` (like in mine), it would be fine.

Comment: Ok, [`next(iter([x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(rx, s)]),'')`](https://ideone.com/YyDQJp)

Comment: Another usual answer to this question is to write a method and you will call it with a one-liner.

Comment: Note that it's sometime possible to obtain this result with little changes in the pattern itself.